# Can't get font to work in rails 4.18 using scss

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, sass

I can't get font to work I don't know what the problem is

from my applications.css.scss

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "negro";
    src: font-url('/assets/fonts/ufonts.com_metrolis-negro-opentype.otf') format('truetype');
}
```

from my application.rb

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

Comment: What does the compiled CSS look like?  Is there an error?  Did you check to verify that your font file is actually being served, rather than the browser receiving a 404?

Comment: Note that CSS's syntax for sources is `src: url(...)`, not `src: font-url(...)`.

Comment: Hey I got it working Yes, I still had to use font-url but i had to shorten the path to just the filename without the pathing in front of it and then it worked ~ thanks, fugee